# Constraint Qualification and Non Linear Optimization

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Why is the objective function a linear combination of gradient of constraints at optimal point for non linear inequality optimizarion under KKT? Intuitive answers please as only in process of masters level math for economists course

Comment: Related thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760709/how-to-prove-lagrange-multiplier-theorem-in-a-rigorous-but-intuitive-way/1760741#1760741

Comment: I have to admit that I don´t understand the question.

Comment: Basically I’m trying to understand the intuition of the constraint qualification calculation. I understand you need to check constraint gradient but don’t really understand how its rank relates to objective function